# Does Blindsight or Tremorsense negate the concealment from a warlocks Shadow Walk?

Tags: dnd-4e

Does Blindsight or Tremorsense negate the concealment which is granted from a warlocks Shadow Walk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** Shadow Walk still affects creatures with Blindsight and Tremorsense.

According to the descriptions of both [Blindsight](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=11) and [Termorsense](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=47), they ignore concealment granted by **illumination** and **invisibility**, but says nothing about other sources of concealment.

So, unless the effect specifically say it alter the light on your square (eg, Drow's [Cloud of Darkness](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2473)), any concealment granted still affects a creature with Blindsight or Tremorsense.